# Using PHP variable in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass a php variable to `mysql_query` such as:

```
$tty = '217';   

$num_of_comments = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id =  '.$tty.'");
$num_of_comments1 = mysql_fetch_array($num_of_comments);
$num_of_comments2 = $num_of_comments1[0];
echo $num_of_comments2 ;
```

However, I am not able to get the value needed in `num_of_comments2`. It returns a 0 on echo.
Also I tried hardcoding 217 in the place of `$tty` in the query. There it works.

I am also aware that this problem can be solved by `mysqli/PDO`. Can someone be kind enough to help me with the code in that case?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement/7537500#7537500

Comment: Not to mention that you posted this question already but for some reason deleted it

Answer (score 0):

you have adding extra dots in query try below

```
$num_of_comments = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id = '$tty'");
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the Prepared Statements of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extensions should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: i haven't dowvoted but probably because `mysql_query`

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your sql. Try with this.

```
$num_of_comments = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id ='$tty'");
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the Prepared Statements of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Why downvote for this solution? .The query will definitely won't work due to the extra dot in it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this

Replace

```
 $num_of_comments = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id =  '.$tty.'");
```

with this

```
 $num_of_comments = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id ='$tty'");
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the Prepared Statements of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$tty = '217';   

$num_of_comments = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE img_id =$tty");
$num_of_comments1 = mysql_fetch_array($num_of_comments);
$num_of_comments2 = $num_of_comments1[0];
echo $num_of_comments2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make difference between fetch_array or fetch_num

try this:

```
 $tty = '217';   

 $num_of_comments = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as counts FROM comments WHERE img_id =  '".$tty."' ");
 $num_of_comments1 = mysql_fetch_array($num_of_comments);
 $num_of_comments2 = $num_of_comments1['counts'];
 echo $num_of_comments2 ;
```